# java how to handle callbacks of rabbitmq messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I want to create a server to handle socket connections from users, and inside my server I want to have a connection to a RabbitMQ, one per connection, but in the examples provided in their webpage I see only "while" loops to wait for the message, in this case I will need to create a thread per connection only to process the message from RabbitMQ.

Is there a way to do this in Java using Spring or any framework that I just create the call back for the RabbitMQ instead of using while loops?

I was using node.js and there it is pretty straightforward to do this,
and I want to know some proposals for Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the Channel.basicConsume and the DefaultConsumer abstract class: https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#consuming

Java concurrency will require a thread for the callback to handle each message, but you can use a thread pool to reuse threads.

```
static final ExecutorService threadPool;

static {
    threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
}
```

Now you need to create a consumer that will handle each delivery by creating a Runnable instance that will be passed to the thread pool to execute.

```
channel.basicConsume(queueName, false, new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
        final byte msgBody = body; // a 'final' copy of the body that you can pass to the runnable
        final long msgTag = envelope.getDeliveryTag();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // handle the message here
                doStuff(msgBody);
                channel.basicAck(msgTag, false);
            }
        };
        threadPool.submit(runnable);
    }
});
```

This shows how you can handle concurrent deliveries on a single connection and channel without a while loop in a single thread that would be blocked on each delivery.  For your sanity, you probably will want to factor your `Runnable` implementation into its own class that could accept the `channel`, `msgBody`, `msgTag` and any other data as parameters that will be accessible when the `run()` method is called.